# How to identify a level between 2 elements in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of grade levels. Now I have a score. I want to find out which level this score is.

```
$levels = array{
      0 => 30
      1 => 60
      2 => 80
      3 => 90
};
$score = 70;
```

In the above example, `$result` should be `1` because `$score >=$levels[1] && $score < $levels[2]`
How to code this when `$score` can be anything between 0 and 100 , and `$levels` can have max 15 elements?

Comment: Just iterate over array and check elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "oneliner" just for fun:

```
$levels = array(
      0 => 30,
      1 => 60,
      2 => 80,
      3 => 90,
);
$score = 70;

$grade = count(array_filter($levels, function($i) use($score) {
    return $i < $score;
})) - 1;

var_dump($grade); // 1
```

Comment: Is this faster than foreach? Does this work even if the $score is a float number?

Comment: @Jenny: 1. it doesn't matter for the array with 15 items 2. What if you check before asking?

Comment: for the moment, my score numbers are all int, so I can't test float.

Comment: @Jenny: you cannot create an array with floats for tests? Here is one `array(40.1, 90.9)`

Answer (score 0):

i never tried this but give it a try:

```
$result = 0;
foreach ($levels as $key => $level)
{
     if($score <= $level)
     {
        break;
     }
     $result = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the previous level separately and update it as long as the score is at least the current level's minimum score:

```
function get_score_level($score, array $levels) 
{
    $prev_level = -1; // assume score less than first level to be invalid

    foreach ($levels as $level => $min_score) {
        if ($score < $min_score) {
            return $prev_level;
        }
        $prev_level = $level;
    }
    return prev_level; // score higher than last level
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If your `$levels` is already sorted in ascending order(as the sample), one loop can solve your problem :

   `function getLevel($score,$level){`

   ```
    for($i=0;$i<count($level)-1;$i++){
         if($score >= $level[$i] && $score < $level[$i+1]){
              $i;
         }
    }
    // the score is greater than last element in $level
    return count($level);
   ```

   `}`
2. If your `$levels` is not sorted and you don't care the key, you can call `sort($level)` to get it sorted.
3. If your `$levels` is not sorted and you want to keep the key, Please tell me what output you want of the following condition and we will disscuss:
   $levels = array{
     0 => 85
     1 => 60
     2 => 80
     3 => 90
   };
   $score = 70;